# Using outer to produce an array of lists

Tags: arrays, r, list

I'm running `outer` on a function that returns a list, and I'm expecting it to return an array of lists, since the documentation says so:

> The outer product of the arrays X and Y is the array A with dimension
>   c(dim(X), dim(Y)) where element A[c(arrayindex.x, arrayindex.y)] =
>   FUN(X[arrayindex.x], Y[arrayindex.y], ...).

However, the following code throws an error:

```
outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x, y) list(x=x, y=y)))
#Error in outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x, y) list(x = x, y = y))) : 
#  dims [product 25] do not match the length of object [50]
```

It seems that `outer` is trying to flatten my lists, whereas I'd like them to be intact. There seems to be no parameter for controlling this (unlike `simplify` for `sapply`). What would you propose? My only requirement is to keep at least two dimensions for indexing purposes down the line.

Comment: Does this help `outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x,y) list(c(x=x, y=y))))` or may be `outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x,y) list(list(x=x, y=y))))`

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @akrun Both are fine. Do you have understanding why this seemingly redundant `list` or `c` wrapper changes the `outer` behaviour?

Comment: @tonytonov The `outer` output is a matrix of dimension equal to product of length of both vectors.  i.e. 25 here.  When we use `list(x=1, y=1)` it is length 2, for all the combinations, the length will be 50.  So, you need something to wrap up that to make it 25.  `list` will wrap that it in a list of 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x,y) list(c(x=x, y=y))))
```

which output a list of 25 elements with each being a named vector

or another option would be to wrap this in a 'list' to create a list of lists.

```
outer(1:5, 1:5, Vectorize(function(x,y) list(list(x=x, y=y))))
```