# `microbenchmark` functions constructed by a factory function

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I have a function that constructs another function according to some specific parameters:

```
factory <- function(param) {
    # some long computation…
    cached.matrix = rnorm(param)

    # return function that uses cached data
    function(other) {
        cached.matrix * cached.matrix + other
    }
}
```

Now, I wanted to benchmark functions generated by the `factory` function for various parameters using the `microbenchmark` package. `microbenchmark` function takes an expression, not a function, and after some experiments I noticed that the following dance with `do.call` and `call` seems to work:

```
params <- seq(5, 100, 5)
list.of.expressions <- sapply(
    params,
    function(param) call('do.call', factory(param), list(7)))
names(list.of.expressions) <- sprintf("f%04d", params)
mb.results <- microbenchmark(list=list.of.expressions, times=10)
```

Is there a simpler way of collecting results of a benchmark of functions parametrized like that, than `call('do.call', …)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show another possible route. What you do is construct unevaluated expressions, while I will be wrapping `microbenchmark` call into a function and using `outer` to produce the desired breakdown.

I'm implicitly assuming that you would like to iterate over two dimensions (in your example, `param` and `other`). I've constructed my own function factory:

```
factory <- function(param) {
  x <- rnorm(param)
  function(mat) {
    t(x) %*% mat %*% x
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to iterate over `param` and `mat`. To make it even more interesting, let `mat` depend on `param` somehow. If that's not the case, just ignore `mat` being a function: it can be a vector.

```
params <- seq(10, 50, 10)
mat1 <- function(param) {diag(param)}
mat2 <- function(param) {matrix(runif(param^2), param)}
```

Here's the function that will go to `outer`, and the call itself:

```
test_factory_med <- Vectorize(function(param, matf) {
         summary(microbenchmark(factory(param)(matf(param))))$median
})
median_tests <- outer(params, c(mat1, mat2), 
                      FUN = function(p, m) test_factory_med(p, m))

colnames(median_tests) <- c("mat1", "mat2")
rownames(median_tests) <- params
median_tests
#      mat1     mat2
#10 15.3150  22.6720
#20 18.6180  36.6355
#30 22.2220  57.9560
#40 27.3265  88.5860
#50 32.7320 129.1250
```

You can preserve a complete set of information from `microbenchmark` by returning a list from it (with a list-wrapping hack from my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410041/using-outer-to-produce-an-array-of-lists)):

```
test_factory_all <- Vectorize(function(param, matf) {
  list(
    list(param = param, 
         matf = mat,
         microbenchmark(factory(param)(matf(param)))))
})

all_tests <- outer(params, c(mat1, mat2), 
                   FUN = function(p, m) test_factory_all(p, m))
all_tests[1, 1]

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$param
#[1] 10
#
#[[1]]$matf
#function (param) 
#{
#    diag(param)
#}
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#Unit: microseconds
#                        expr    min     lq     mean median     uq    max neval
# factory(param)(matf(param)) 14.414 15.315 17.17081 15.916 16.516 88.586   100
```

Edit: in response to the comment below, here's how you can measure only the calls  to functions that came out from the factory.

```
# exclude costs for running factory
test_factory_med1 <- Vectorize(function(param, matf) {
         f <- factory(param)
         summary(microbenchmark(f(matf(param))))$median
})

# exclude costs for both running factory and constructing parameter
test_factory_med2 <- Vectorize(function(param, matf) {
         f <- factory(param)
         m <- matf(param)
         summary(microbenchmark(f(m)))$median
})
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't want to benchmark the factory function, just the result. Won't `microbenchmark(factory(param)(matf(param)))` count time of both the factory call and the returned function call?

Comment: @liori Yes, it will. Isn't it what you're after? What do you mean by "benchmark just the result"?

Comment: If you're only interested in benchmarking the final call (minus the cost for `factory(param)`, I suppose that's what you mean above), put the `factory(param)` out of `microbenchmark`: `fp <- factory(param); microbenchmark(fp(matf(param)))`

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested in exactly this—otherwise I wouldn't write the factory function in the first place. Thank you; so, essentially, you're merging the results of several `microbenchmark` runs instead of, like I tried, running a single big one. That's a good clue. This makes it easier to just put the result of the factory function into the environment, so that you can just call it by name from inside the `microbenchmark` call.

Comment: Makes sense, agreed. As you can see from the edit, the general concept can be easily adapted for virtually anything you want to include/exclude in your measurements.